# how to store phonetics in mysql database

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have to store the phonetics of words in a database in this format:

```
blow = \ˈblō\
```

But when I see in the database, it's stored like this:

```
blow = \?bl?\
```

There are `?` instead of symbols you can see.

Please correct me as to what I am doing wrong.

Thanks

Comment: Most likely an encoding issue. Make sure you go UTF-8 all the way.

Comment: Consult this => http://stackoverflow.com/q/279170/

Comment: What is the data type of your field in mysql?

Comment: @DatzMe   datatype is text

Comment: try to read this one pal... http://dev.hubspot.com/blog/bid/7049/MySQL-and-Unicode-Three-Gotchas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

your database does not support all characters i would recommend to change it to something like this:

```
character set: utf8
collation: utf8_general_ci
```

right now you have a standard character set and thats why it changes to ?????